# Why is my code failing to pass parameters from JavaScript to JSP using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write JavaScript code which, on a mouse click event, sends some parameter (id) to the server-side JSP code. The JSP code then returns a string to the JavaScript.

...and the response text will be a string returned from JSP specified in `out.println(substring);`.

This code is not working. Sorry if I am doing something silly; I am new to coding for the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` is an *asynchronous* request by default, meaning that after you call `send`, *the next line of code is executed before the request has finished*. The code to be executed when the request finished goes into your "state change" handler. You're already assigning a state change handler here:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange
```

But you never define what `handleRequestStateChange` actually is. You should probably [read about ready states and the onreadystatechange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started#section_3).

Try the following code instead:

```
<button type="button" onClick="handleButtonClick();">Click Me!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleButtonClick()
{
    // Declare the variables we'll be using
    var xmlHttp, handleRequestStateChange;

    // Define the function to be called when our AJAX request's state changes:
    handleRequestStateChange = function()
    {
        // Check to see if this state change was "request complete", and
        // there was no server error (404 Not Found, 500 Server Error, etc)
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            var substring=xmlHttp.responseText;
            // Do something with the text here
            alert(substring);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://csce:8080/test/index.jsp?id=c6c684d9cc99476a7e7e853d77540ceb", true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

This code assigns to `handleRequestStateChange` a function which will be called when the ready state of the `XMLHttpRequest` changes. The function checks to see if the ready state is `4` (request finished and response is ready) and if so, the you will be able to access the responseText property of the request which will contain the response from the JSP page.

As a suggestion for the future, when you've learned how AJAX request work, you may find a helper library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes tasks like this much easier!

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for valuable information....I tried the code but somehow its not working...may be i am missing something should I take care of some stuff when i want to run this code. Since I copied the code to the body of html message and tried to run.. there was no output...am I doing some stupid mistake....

Comment: @Judy I'm actually not in my office at the moment and can't easily test this code. Maybe someone else can help you... in the meantime, try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox -- it's great for debugging JavaScript code!

Comment: . Thanks for your help... Actually i debugged from httpfox but I can't see any request going or any page being called.... Thanks again for the concern..

Comment: You can also set it to work synchronously `http.open("POST", url, false);` in which case it will wait until it's done before executing the next line of JS.

Comment: @Antinous you _can_ but you shouldn't: this will normally cause the entire browser to block, preventing user interaction, until the request completes. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request ("synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience")

Comment: This isn't something that worries me, as I apply it to logging in. I don't want the user to do anything until the login has been confirmed. I've had no problems with it so far. Do you mean the browser might "lock up" (turn grey). In which case, I'd agree it's best not to use synchronous... If it's been deprecated then you should only use asynchronous anyway. I didn't know that. In fact I've just discovered JQuery's `$.post` which is wonderful and has callbacks for success, and I think error. Seems a bit cleaner code than `XMLHttpRequest` too, to me at least.

Answer (score 2):

In your case (GET method) you need to pass the variables in the **open** method directly (at the end of the url)

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://csce:8080/test/index.jsp?id=c6c684d9cc99476a7e7e853d77540ceb", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

---

Goyuix's technic is **only** correct in the case of the POST method:

```
xhr.open("POST", "http://csce:8080/test/index.jsp", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("id=c6c684d9cc99476a7e7e853d77540ceb");
```

---

You might want to use the ***uri encoding global function*** as a good practice in case you have spaces or other special characters in your parameter:

**POST method:**

```
var myVar1 = encodeURIComponent("c6c684d9cc99476a7e7e853d77540ceb");
xhr.open("POST", "http://csce:8080/test/index.jsp", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("id=" + myVar1);
```

**GET method:**

```
var myVar1 = encodeURIComponent("c6c684d9cc99476a7e7e853d77540ceb");
xhr.open("GET", "http://csce:8080/test/index.jsp?id=" + myVar1, true);
```

---

FYI, this is how you **retrieve the parameters passed to the JSP page**:

*We are using JSP's core library (this lib must be in your web app's /WEB-INF/lib/ directory) to output the value of the parameter called "id".*

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:out value="${param.id}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pass **null** in the send method, try passing something like "key=value" which should then show up in your JSP Request object, and you can access it by calling something like:

```
string myValue = request.getParameter("key");
```

Comment: I am not sure since I read a tutorial on AJAX and they specified that if POST messages are sent then we need to pass some value in send().

Comment: Thanks Goyuix for your response I will try what you have suggested